# Character Limits on Posts in Current Graph API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking for confirmation of the character limits on posts & comments when creating them through the current version of the graph API. A while ago the limit was 420 characters, however the news at F8 was a bump to 60,000.

In initial testing on our end, it seems we can exceed 420 but we see some performance degradation.

Two questions then:

1. Current character limit on posts & comments
2. Whether others have seen performance degrade with size of post.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to make a post larger than 420, but my guess would be that Facebook is still working on scaling the Graph API to handle the larger requests. It should be possible to make these requests; however, you may have to be ready to accept an error and try again. I would imagine that performance will get better as time goes on.